# Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 how to get channel by name

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Created channel from java SDK

```
Channel newChannel = hfclient.
                 newChannel("foo", anOrderer, channelConfiguration, channelConfig);
```

In the docker container log channel created successfully

Questions:

1. Cannot create channel with the same name - get 400 BAD REQUEST
   The channel exists?
2. I cannot get channel by name hfclient.getChannel("") = null
3. How can I get created channel?
4. How can I check list of existing channels from docker container ?

Answer (score 2):

You can query for available channels by invoking [CSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/cscc/configure.go#L45) (Configuration System Chaincode), which provides following APIs:

```
// These are function names from Invoke first parameter
const (
    JoinChain      string = "JoinChain"
    GetConfigBlock string = "GetConfigBlock"
    GetChannels    string = "GetChannels"
)
```

And Java SDK code to do it looks like this:

```
    final Channel channel = client.newChannel("");

    channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer0", "grpc://localhost:7050"));
    channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer0", "grpc://localhost:7051"));

    channel.initialize();

    final TransactionProposalRequest proposalRequest = client.
                                                   newTransactionProposalRequest();

    final ChaincodeID chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
            .setName("cscc")
            .setPath("github.com/C0rWin/pgdays/chaincode/personsV3")
            .build();

    proposalRequest.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);
    proposalRequest.setFcn("GetChannels");
    proposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));

    final Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.
                                          sendTransactionProposal(proposalRequest);
```